# Qt - QFileSystemModel How to Get Files in Folder (Noob)

Tags: c++, qt

I have following Code to list the files in the listView:

```
fileModel = new QFileSystemModel(this);
ui->listView->setModel(fileModel);
ui->listView->setRootIndex(fileModel->setRootPath(filePath));
```

I would like to get a list/Map to the files in a Path. how can this be done?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following snippet will do what you want :

```
QList<QString> path_list;
QModelIndex parentIndex = fileModel->index(filePath);
int numRows = fileModel->rowCount(parentIndex);

for (int row = 0; row < numRows; ++row) {
    QModelIndex childIndex = fileModel->index(row, 0, parentIndex);
    QString path = fileModel->data(childIndex).toString();
    path_list.append(path);
}
```

There is one thing that you should not forget. From the [documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/QFileSystemModel.html#caching-and-performance) :

> Unlike QDirModel(obsolete), QFileSystemModel uses a separate thread to
>   populate itself so it will not cause the main thread to hang as the
>   file system is being queried. Calls to rowCount() will return 0 until
>   the model populates a directory.

Hence, you have to wait until you receive `directoryLoaded(const QString & path)` signal from QFileSystemModel after you initiate the model, then fill your list.

Comment: Is it possible to check whether it is a directory or a file?

Comment: You can use `QFileInfo(filePath + "\\" + path).isDir()` in the loop which i showed in my answer. This will return true if the current `path` is a directory.