# Use QCompleter programmatically without widget

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qcompleter

I struggle to use [QCompleter](http://%20https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcompleter.html) programmatically without a widget. I expect this to show me all directories in my root `/` directory:

```
QCompleter *completer = new QCompleter();

QFileSystemModel *fsModel = new QFileSystemModel(completer);
fsModel->setRootPath(QString());

completer->setModel(fsModel);

completer->setCompletionPrefix(QString("/"));

for (int i = 0; completer->setCurrentRow(i); i++)
    qDebug() << completer->currentCompletion() << " is match number " << i;
```

The `currentCompletion()` returns an emtpy string and what I saw is that the model index seems to be invalid.

**Note**: If I run the same code and attach the completer to a e.g. `QLineEdit` (with `myLineEdit->setCompleter(completer);`) the completion works as expected.

Comment: Have a look https://stackoverflow.com/a/24716855/492293

Comment: @Gandalf Thanks. Do you refer to the fact that the index is not yet ready and I should somehow wait for `directoryLoaded(const QString & path)`?

Comment: You are welcome. Yes you should wait for it.